# How do I get around IE8 limitation of live('change') not firing on AJAX elements?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.3.2, and I cannot update that version because of spec limitations.

I am trying to fire an event, where a user goes directly to targeted pages using a 'Jump Menu'. This jump menu is AJAX based. First Country, which gets an AJAX result of States, then Cities. When user clicks on a city, they are to be directed to the relevant URL.

This code works fine in Mozilla, Chrome and IE9:

`$("#id-of-the-AJAXED-select-widget").live('change', function(){
            jumpSubmit();
        });`

But the 'change' event does not fire in IE8. From what I read in many other places, this is a combination of issues with IE8 and jQuery 1.3 - however, there were no ideas for solutions. Much as I would like, I cannot banish either of these - so kindly help me find an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaner way to write your code: `$("#id-of-the-AJAXED-select-widget").live('change', jumpSubmit);`.

As for your problem, that seems to be IE8-specific. Your best bet would be to single out IE8 and then use the `click()` event instead of the `change()` event to trigger the page:

```
// mousedown
oldIndex = this.index

// mouseup
if (this.index != oldIndex) {
  // It changed
}
```

Comment: @Elliot, that is the correct answer, but on v.1.3.2 live() or bind are the only methods.

Comment: Hi, this worked with a slight improvisation. I did: `$("#id-of-the-AJAXED-select-widget option").live('change', jumpSubmit);` However, there's a delay before the redirect happens, suggesting that the event does not fire immediately (only in IE8). Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Odd. It could be IE8's slow JS engine, but maybe it's just IE8. Try adding in an `alert()` right before your redirect code. If it fires correctly, the problem is with IE8 itself.

Comment: Okay, it appears that unless I click on something else after I click the <option>, it won't fire. When I have the alert, it works as soon as I dismiss the alert box. When I remove the alert, I choose an option, click on something else, and then wait a while before it begins to redirect. :(

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these solutions worked - I resorted to showing a click button for IE8 users. I'm accepting your answer for coming close to what I needed, and also responding to my comments :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `live` you'll have to use `bind`, so:

- either bind the the event to your element and "rebind" in ajax requests that replace it
- or, bind the `select` element, and make your ajax calls so that they only replace the `option`s in the `select` (I'm guessing choosing a city is done via a `select` element)

Let me know if you need further clarifications.

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, `bind` is also non-responsive. Curiously, bind doesn't even work in Mozilla...